# Filling edges of an array with specific value

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to use this code to change only the edges of an existing array to zeroes:

```
for (row = 0; row < 12; row++) {
       for (col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
           if (row == 0 || row == 11 || col == 0 || col == 9) {
               myArray[row][col] = 0;
           }
       }
  }
```

It is only working for the first row and doesn't change any of the other values after that.
What could be my issue?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/hSsmM4). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: On a personal note I would think it would be clearer if you use four consecutive simple non-nested loops instead, one for each edge. So you first (for example) cleared `myArray[0]`, then `myArray[11]`, then `myArray[i][0]` followed lastly by `myArray[i][9]`. Or why not simply initialize *all* arrays to zero to begin with, and then just "fill" the non-edge elements with values?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong, the error is probably somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working. Maybe you're not printing it correctly, or not setting it correctly:

```
int myArray[12][12];
for (int row = 0; row < 12; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        myArray[row][col] = 1;
        if (row == 0 || row == 11 || col == 0 || col == 9) {
            myArray[row][col] = 0;
        }
        printf("%d", myArray[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

[image: Code output]

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you are concerned about EDGES and not SIDES of a 2D matrix.

For the earlier, you can use something like this instead of loops for obvious reasons.

[1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBC7o.jpg)

And for SIDES, in your nested loop, you can use the if-else ladder for row=0, ROW_SIZE-1  col=0, COL_SIZE-1 like this

[2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJcB0.jpg)
It should be good enough, still has scope for optimizations.

Comment: It would be easier to read if you could copy / paste the code. Second best would be to inline the images.